# Error at line 30174

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

This might be a duplicate question but I have searched for this a lot but didnt get a proper answer

In one of my activity I'm using 2 viewpager's and the content of the viewpager's are coming from database.

the activity is working properly as its expected when I've started the app and executing it completely and finally closing it, but if i make my app background while that activity is opened

and start 5-6 other apps and then again come back to this app I'm getting this error

```
01-10 05:28:48.620: E/SQLiteLog(5770): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-10 05:28:48.620: E/SQLiteLog(5770): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(//JKBADP.sqlite) - 
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770): Failed to open database 'JKBADP.sqlite'.
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at com.winit.dropbox.databaseaccess.DatabaseHelper.openDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:189)
01-10 05:28:48.625: E/SQLiteDatabase(5770):     at com.winit.dropbox.dataaccesslayer.DepartmentDA.getallDepartment(DepartmentDA.java:84)
```

The whole error is too big to post here so I've posted only the initial few lines, I think this error at line 30174 problem is the real issue

I've saved the database path and name in a separate class and the string variables are static.

I have tried binding all the controls and the initialization in onresume method, but that also didn't help.

Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: May be your database path becomes null after come back to your activity. Androids Garbage Collector will called if needs memory.

Comment: Ari, Did you get any success with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to close your database and re-open it on resume

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db.open();
    }
```

plus your Database path should be defined in following manner:

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                    + mContext.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
DB_NAME = "DatabaseName"
String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Comment: Nop i checked it again, I have the db path saved in another constant class, the path gets cleared, that's why I'm facing this problem I think, I tried to fetch the path again in onresume, but is not working

Comment: Have you closed your database on onPause()? Plus when you are trying to do db.open; is db pointing to null? please check.

Comment: Opening and closing is not a problem, the problem is if my app is in background and I'm using other apps say 5-6 other apps, then in the meantime the database path gets flushed, so when it is again trying to open it doesn't know the path of the database

Comment: I think same comment was given by Jay.. Check your database path onresume and onstart()